# DRF --405 Method not allowed for update operation

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework, http-status-code-405

[image]I have done this before and may be it did work properly that time but now suddenly it's not working as it's expected to be.

The viewset.py:

```
   class ProfileViewSet(ModelViewSet):
      serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
      http_method_names = ["post", "get", "put", "delete"]
      queryset = Profile.objects.all()

      def get(self, request, format=None):
          users = Profile.objects.all()
          serializer = ProfileSerializer(users, many=True)
          return Response(serializer.data)

      def put(self, request, pk, format=None):
          snippet = self.get_object(pk)
          serializer = ProfileSerializer(snippet, data=request.data)
          if serializer.is_valid():
             serializer.save()
             return Response(serializer.data)
          return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
     user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    

     full_name = models.CharField(_("Name of User"), blank=True, null=True, 
     max_length=255)
    
     phone_number = PhoneNumberField()
     zip_code = models.CharField(_("Zip Code"), blank=True, null=True, max_length=255)
     def __str__(self):
         return self.user.username
```

**seralizers.py**

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'
```

**urls.py**

```
router.register("profile/<int:pk>", ProfileViewSet, basename="profile_each")
```

whenever I hit in postman It says  "405 Method not allowed".

Am I missing anything here please?

Comment: You don't need to define your pk in your url, just make something like this `router.register("profile", ProfileViewSet, basename="profile_each")`

Comment: Show the url.py file

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a ViewClass, you need define it as a view.

```
router.register("profile/<int:pk>", ProfileViewSet.as_view(), basename="profile_each")
```